# Using Sockets to communicate Desktop MFC C++ and DataBase

Tags: c++, sockets, visual-c++, mfc

In my company, I developed long years ago a big MFC C++ 6.0 app that is implemented server-client platform. This app uses ODBC to communicate to a Database.

Recently app was audited in security aspects, however among others risk securitys, one of them was a big risk when app is communicating via ODBC with Database. According auditor company, data travel in not secured way and must be minimized by using Sockets.

The App doesn't work via HTTP because it is just a stand-alone exe. I need help how to implement sockets communication between app and database server.

I know MFC C++ in init method calls AfxSocketInit(); however I see complicated to implement this.

Comment: Random set of words. I am not surprised at all that such random set of words came from auditors, who are known to know nothing but still perform technical audit. But it is a job of the developer to translate this rubbish to proper technical english.

Comment: Perhaps use CSocket derived classes?

Comment: It is not odbc itself that is the major problem, but the lack of encryption